# Javascript copies objects by reference. But the below code I assigned one object with null. But the other object still has the same value

Tags: javascript, object, reference

Here there are two objects, user and user1. The user is copied to user1. The user is then assigned to null, but the user1 does not change.

```js
let user = {
    name : 'Nagendra Kamath',
    age : 22,
    goodMorn(){
        console.log('Good Morning '+ this.name);
    }
};

let user1 = user;

user = null; 


user1.goodMorn(); // even if we have assigned user to null the value of user1 remains same
user.goodMorn();  // throws an error
```

Please tell me how is this possible??

Comment: `user` is the reference to the object, not object. reassignment of the reference will not mutate or change the actual object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you create an Object that exist in memory, and reference `user` to this object.

```
let user = {
    name : 'Nagendra Kamath',
    age : 22,
    goodMorn(){
        console.log('Good Morning '+ this.name);
    }
};
```

Now you assign a new reference `user1` to the same Object.

```
let user1 = user;
```

Now you assign to `user` value `null`

```
user = null;
```

But the Object is still exist, and reference `user1` to the object also exist, so it's fine that

```
user1.goodMorn(); // works, because it's still a reference to the object.
user.goodMorn();  // throws an error, because it's value is null
```

Important thing here: `user1` is not a reference to `user`, because `user` is also a reference. `user1` is a reference to the original Object in memory, `user1` is the similar reference as reference `user`

Comment: Ohh.. Ok. So the object in memory will be intact until it is totally isolated.